# I want to remove the question mark from Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which in which the email section looks like below.

```
0                        dine@flavourofindia.co??
1                    thaipothong@bigpond.com.au??
```

I want to remove the '??' mark from it. I tried to `str.replace()` function, but it isn't working in the case of a question mark. What to do?

Comment: Could you please share the code you've tried?

Comment: ```df['email'] = df['email'].str.replace('?', '')```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `str.strip`:

```
df[1].str.strip('?')
```

Output:

```
0        dine@flavourofindia.co
1    thaipothong@bigpond.com.au
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

`str.replace` should work also:

```
df[1].str.replace('?','')
```

Output:

```
0        dine@flavourofindia.co
1    thaipothong@bigpond.com.au
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks.  ```str.replace('?', '')``` isn't working, i tried that before posting this question.